# HttpSelfHostServer connection actively refused

Tags: c#, .net, https, self-hosting

I'm encountering a very strange issue with `HttpSelfHostServer` in .NET: The HTTP server **works fine for 12-24 hours** (I haven't figured out the real cause of its failure), and after that it starts actively refusing connections from clients. The odd thing: Not even killing the server process and restarting it helps; Only a clean reboot of the server machine will fix the problem. I have reproduced the exact same behavior on 3 different machines, so it's not a problem with my local configuration. To me it looks like a problem somewhere deep down inside windows or .NET.

Here's the exception I get on client machines:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.. ---> System.IO.IOException: Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at ProELS.Car.Client.ProELSCarClient.SendMessageEnvelope(MessageEnvelope envelope, String host) in c:\Source\Kunden\ARB\ProELS.Car\ProELS.Car.Client\ProELSCarClient.cs:line 520
   at ProELS.Car.Client.ProELSCarClient.SendMessageEnvelope(MessageEnvelope envelope) in c:\Source\Kunden\ARB\ProELS.Car\ProELS.Car.Client\ProELSCarClient.cs:line 485
   at ProELS.Car.Client.ProELSCarClient.TestAuthentication() in c:\Source\Kunden\ARB\ProELS.Car\ProELS.Car.Client\ProELSCarClient.cs:line 239
   at ProELS.Car.TestClient.Form1.btnTryAuthentication_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Source\Kunden\ARB\ProELS.Car.TestClient\ProELS.Car.TestClient\Form1.cs:line 170
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.. ---> System.IO.IOException: Von der Übertragungsverbindung können keine Daten gelesen werden: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
```

And here's the code I use to start the server:

```
 private void StartCarServer()
        {

            HttpSelfHostServer carServer;
            var config = new ExtendedHttpSelfHostConfiguration("https://localhost:8082");

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            carServer = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            carServer.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }
```

My only possible explanation is that maybe the `HttpSelfHostServer` is not really made for clean TLS/SSL usage, since it was a pretty bad configuration nightmare to get it working in the first place?

Comment: I have solved this problem elegantly... I dumped the useless HttpSelfHostServer and purchased WebServer.NET from WeOnlyDo Software. Now the self hosted server works like a charm 24x7. I'm not affiliated in any way with WeOnlyDo Software, but I can definitely recommend their product if any of you encounter problems with self hosted HTTP*S* under .NET